# Cannot use git hub extension as root

Tags: git, github, homebrew, root

What do I need to run [git hub](http://github.com/github/hub)  as root?

`git hub` works perfectly in non root user.

To install it as root, I ran `brew install hub` which lead to

```
# brew install hub                                                                                                                                 
W: be careful as root.

========================================================================
You may want to update following environments after installed linuxbrew.

  PATH, MANPATH, INFOPATH

(example: /usr/share/doc/linuxbrew-wrapper/examples/profile)
========================================================================
Don't run this as root!
/usr/lib/linuxbrew-wrapper/install:110: warning: Insecure world writable dir /root in PATH, mode 040777
```

It seems to linked with `brew` ran as root.

The alternative would be to use `sudo -u`, but the command is not recognized. Why is it so?

```
$ sudo -u user 'git hub user myuser'
sudo: git hub user myuser: command not found
```

Comment: From the [brew FAQ](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#why-does-homebrew-say-sudo-is-bad-) : `Homebrew is designed to work without using sudo. You can decide to use it but we strongly recommend not to do so. `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to install hub from a regular user.

```
$ brew install hub
```

and to add `/usr/local/bin` to the `$PATH` of root user (if it's not already the case.)

For this, you can use the following command:

```
echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

In this way, the `/usr/local/bin` appears before `/usr/bin`, and if a command if present in both location, the homebrew version has the priority.

Comment: Yes, but you have to remember each time to type `sudo -u non_root_user`. My solution is cleaner.